# cat filename | cut -f2 | head -1 > newfile contains more characters than expected

Tags: command-line, files, php, cut, head

When I run:

```
cat filename | cut -f3 | head -1
```

I get the following result:

```
apple
```

However when I save this to a file by using:

```
cat filename | cut -f3 | head -1 > newfile
```

I then open this using php with the following:

```
$variable = file_get_contents("newfile"); 
echo $variable; // PRINTS "apple"
```

But when I do the following the output is 6!!!

```
echo strlen($variable); // PRINTS 6 WHEN I EXPECT 5!
$variable = "apple";
echo $variable; // NOW PRINTS 5
```

Any idea how to avoid this? I need to use this variable in a lookup function and it wont match my lookup due to the extra character which I cannot identify.

When I echo the following:

```
$variable = file_get_contents("newfile"); 
echo "TEST1";
echo "TEST2";
echo $variable;
echo "TEST3";
echo "TEST4";
```

I get the following output:

```
TEST1TEST2apple
TEST3TEST4
```

So it must be printing a new line somehow....?!?

Comment: Thanks. I want the output to be TEST1TEST2appleTEST3TEST4 all in one line. Meaning php should see just the 5 chars.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Indeed, that's your `\n`, that is counted by strlen

In PHP, you have `rtrim` (http://php.net/manual/fr/function.rtrim.php) to remove all `\n`, `\t`, `\r`, `\0` & `\x0B` from the right end of your string.

Comment: Perfect thank you so much. I wasn't aware of this function!